# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous for IF statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where each value in row 1 is a number 1, 2, or 3. I'm trying to build a new DataFrame for each item in list 1, 2, or 3. My code is currently trying to read the column value for each Item in row 1 and append the column to the proper DataFrame (preferably as a view).

My IF statement issues the following error and I have no idea how to solve it or why I get it:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
for z in range(len(df2.columns)):
    if df2.loc[1].iloc[[z]] == 1:
        # Append column to df5 and move on
    elif df2.loc[1].iloc[[z]] == 2:
...
```

This also does not work for:

```
    if df2.loc[1].iloc[[z]] == '1':
```

I'm fairly confident this approach should work as later on in my code I pass a similar argument

```
for d in range(len(df3)):
    if df3.loc[d,] == df4['Column Name'].loc[a,]:
        #stuff here works
...
```

Comment: python has a built in enumerator aptly called `enumerate` no need to use `range` + `len`, are you able to create an example of what you're trying to attempt ? your code doesn't seem that optimized nor readable.

Comment: Thats my logic for the for loop. In my code df2 is named pLoad and the append logic doesnt exist yet but the second for loop with df3 works perfectly fine. For recreating the issue, I import the DataFrames from csv's and then manipulate them, so I'm not really sure how to generate equivalent data right for you. Its about 300 cells of info a column which is why I dont want to work through more than the rows I need to.